# Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, matrix) into Type TensorType(float32, matrix)

Tags: theano

I wrote a python program execute correctly in a computer. But when i put it in another computer, It has such a problem:

```
  TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, matrix) (of Variable <TensorType(float64, matrix)>) into Type TensorType(float32, matrix).
```

There is no bugs in the codes because i can run it correctly in my computer. But why it has such a problem in another computer?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't explicitly specify the datatype of a theano tensor, it will attribute `theano.config.floatX`, of which the default can vary according to systems.

The error you have here usually comes from using a numpy array of dtype `float64` and trying to feed it into a theano function that was built for `float32` (either `floatX == 'float32'` or you specified it explicitly).

A remedy for this is to be explicit at every step about dtype. If you want to use a GPU at some point, sticking to `float32` is best at the moment. Just declare every single tensor and numpy array as `float32`.